# linter-jshint lint JavaScript inside markdown file in Atom editor

Tags: jshint, atom-editor

The package I am using is `linter-jshint`, even after I add the `.jshintignore` file both in the project directory and home directory. It still lints the JavaScripe code inside the `.md` file.

How to make it only lint the file with `.js` extension.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is actually a bug in the core `language-gfm` package. The base `linter` determines which providers to invoke using the scopes that grammars provide us, the `language-gfm` grammar provides incorrect scopes which results in linter-jshint being triggered in markdown files, it provides us `source.js`, instead of `source.embedded.js`.

You can find more info about this bug in [`atom/language-gfm#121`](https://github.com/atom/language-gfm/issues/121).

As a workaround you can disable `language-gfm` package and install the `language-markdown` package.